# Ignore zero in std::min and calculate minimum of other numbers

Tags: c++, minimum, divide-by-zero

Minimum of non-zero numbers:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    
        double s1 = 1000;
        double s2 = 400;
        double s3 = 300;
        double s4 = 10;     
            
        double minimum = std::min({s1, s2, s3, s4});
        
        std::cout<<minimum<<"\n";
        
        double var = 1/minimum;
        
        std::cout<<var;
}
```

This works fine and returns:

```
10
0.1
```

Problem is when one of the numbers is zero:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    
        double s1 = 1000;
        double s2 = 400;
        double s3 = 300;
        double s4 = 0;      
            
        double minimum = std::min({s1, s2, s3, s4});
        
        std::cout<<minimum<<"\n";
        
        double var = 1/minimum;
        
        std::cout<<var;
}
```

It returns:

```
0
inf
```

Expected results:

```
300
0.00333333
```

How can I ignore zero from the calculation?

Comment: Well the `std::min` function is working as intended, it returns the smallest value. If you want to ignore zero, then you need to remove it from the list of values that you pass to `std::min`. A simple way is to put the values in a container, use [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to remove zeros, and use e.g. [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) on the container.

Comment: You could pass a lambda as the second argument for comparing operator and ignoring the numbers you want to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::min` works as it should work if you have special requirements, you could pass a compare function with the following signature:

```cpp
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

as the second `std::min` function argument (the `Compare` template parameter):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    double s1 = 1000;
    double s2 = 400;
    double s3 = 300;
    double s4 = 0;

    auto const ignore_zero = [](auto const& a, auto const& b) -> bool {
        if(0 == a)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(0 == b)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return a < b;
    };

    double minimum = std::min({s1, s2, s3, s4}, ignore_zero);
    std::cout << minimum << "\n";
}
```

---

But it's strange, I suggest you if you have such special requirement with your code:

1. Try to redesign your program.
2. Use a function/functor helper:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace core::helper
{
template<typename T>
struct special_find final
{
    std::vector<T> nums;
    explicit special_find(std::initializer_list<T> nums_)
        : nums(std::move(nums_))
    {
    }

    auto min() const
    {
        return *std::min_element(nums.cbegin(), nums.cend());
    }
    special_find& ignore(T const& value)
    {
        nums.erase(std::remove_if(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [&value](auto const & item)
        {
            return item == value;
        }), nums.end());
        return *this;
    }
};
} // namespace core::helper

int main()
{
    double s1 = 1000;
    double s2 = 400;
    double s3 = 300;
    double s4 = 0;

    auto const min = core::helper::special_find({s1, s2, s3, s4}).ignore(0).min();
    std::cout << min << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Your `ignore_zero` lambda does not satisfy the requirements of [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare), which I think makes the behavior undefined. I ran a test where I copied your code, then swapped the initializations of `s1` and `s4` (so `s1` was 0, while `s4` was 1000), compiled, and got `0` as the result. The problem is that `!ignore_zero(a,b) && !(ignore_zero(b,a)` does not establish an equivalence relation. More concretely, `ignore_zero(a,0)` should evaluate to `true` whenever `a` is non-zero.

Comment: Another issue is that this can still return a zero if all arguments are zero.

Answer (score 2):

Or like this

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr double min_no_zero(const double (&values)[N])
{
    static_assert(N>0,"There must be at least one number");
    double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    for (const auto value : values)
    {
        if ( value != 0.0 )
        {
            min = std::min(min, value);
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr double s1 = 1000.0;
    constexpr double s2 = 400.0;
    constexpr double s3 = 0.0;
    constexpr double s4 = 10.0;

    static_assert( min_no_zero({ s1, s2, s3, s4 }) == 10.0);
}
```

Comment: This returns `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` if all values are zero or if `N` is zero.

Comment: @G.Sliepen good point, but the only requirement was it should not return 0.0. I'll add the check for 0 elements though ;) Maybe the requirement should have been to replace 0.0 with std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon(). I'll leave that to the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't pass the 0s to min. I guess that's the only general answer without knowing how your input looks like.